# how can I update a state in react using axios.get method?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-state, react-state-management

I have a layout where there is a navbar as a separate component and the remaining of the page, my problem is when I change the showing Classes in the navbar I want the page to change it's states to show the related info for each class, I am getting all the needed info from the navbar, so the problem is not there, I think the problem is in the Class.js file on how to update the state, please help anyone, here is the Class.js file:

```
class Class extends React.Component {
    
    static contextType = userContext
    
    state = {
        Curriculum: [],
        Classworks: [], 
        Homeworks: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.location.state)
        const provided = this.props.location.state.ClassNumber
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }; 
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Elearning/Curriculum/${provided}`, config)
            .then(
                res => {
                    this.setState(
                        {
                            Curriculum: res.data 
                        }
                    );
                }
            )                      
      }
      componentDidUpdate(){
        const provided = this.props.location.state.ClassNumber
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }; 
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Elearning/Curriculum/${provided}`, config)
            .then(
                res => {
                    this.setState(
                        {
                            Curriculum: res.data 
                        }
                    );
                }
            )  
      }
    render()
        {       
            console.log(this.state.Curriculum);       
            return(
            <div className="back">
            <Navbar/>
            
            <main className= "MainContent">
                <div className="Class">
                    <h2 className="class">
                        {this.props.location.state.Name}
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <Tabs  className="Tabs" defaultActiveKey="1" centered>
                    <TabPane tab="Curriculum"  key="1">
                        <List
                        itemLayout="horizontal"
                        dataSource={this.state.Curriculum}
                        renderItem={item => (
                            <List.Item>
                                <Table striped bordered hover size="sm" >
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            #
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Title
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {item.Title}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </Table>
                            </List.Item>
                        )}
                        />
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="ClassWorks"  key="2">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="HomeWorks" key="3">
                        
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="Videos" key="4">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="Sessions" key="5">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="quizzes" key="6">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="Exams" key="7">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                </Tabs>
            </main>
            <br/>
            <footer className="Footer">Designed by Eng. Omar Redwan</footer>
        </div>
        )}
}
```

Comment: what's the issue at this moment? I see you are already setting the state with the retrieved data.

Comment: that is correct, but when I try to show another class using the navbar, it does not change the state, it only takes the state assigned at first, and the navbar sends the related info correctly, but the Class.js does not use it to change it's state and get the info related to that class from the api

Comment: u mean in the TabPane? Where is the part showing the change of class? You change the class in parent component?

Comment: Is this all being rendered in a router? Is `ClassNumber` part of *some* route state sent from a link in `Navbar`? What is the issue? Are you trying to switch the `TabPane tab="Curriculum"` tab? I don't see an issue with how state is updated, so it is a bit unclear what you think the issue is.

Comment: yes, I am using a router and the link sends the ClassNumber, the Name and it sends them with no problems and I check the info using the consol.log, but It does not get the info from the api once the props.location change, how can I make it use axios to get the info once the props.location that the files receives from the navbar changes??

Comment: Is the problem with updating state

Comment: yes, I want to update the state once the props.location change

Comment: What is the value of `const provided = this.props.location.state.ClassNumber` in `componentDidUpdate`? If it is what you expect then you should check your network tab in the browser's dev tools to see what the request looks like, and what any response it. If the network request/response is good then check what `res.data` is in the component. You need to trace/follow the data flow to see where it changes to something unexpected.

Comment: this is inside the props.location that the link in the navbar passes, and I use it to call the api to get the different info related to the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with updating the state right?. Then
you have to pass prevProps and prevState as params to componentDidUpdate. To track the changes in props you have to fetch prevProps and componentDidUpdate calls only when there is a change in props. That means when the location props changes then it will update the state which you needed to do.

```
class Class extends React.Component {
    
    static contextType = userContext
    
    state = {
        Curriculum: [],
        Classworks: [], 
        Homeworks: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.location.state)
        const provided = this.props.location.state.ClassNumber
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }; 
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Elearning/Curriculum/${provided}`, config)
            .then(
                res => {
                    this.setState(
                        {
                            Curriculum: res.data 
                        }
                    );
                }
            )                      
      }
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
if(prevProps.location.state.classNumber!==this.props.location.state.classNumber){
        const provided = this.props.location.state.ClassNumber
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }; 
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Elearning/Curriculum/${provided}`, config)
            .then(
                res => {
                    this.setState(
                        {
                            Curriculum: res.data 
                        }
                    );
                }
            )
}  
      }
    render()
        {       
            console.log(this.state.Curriculum);       
            return(
            <div className="back">
            <Navbar/>
            
            <main className= "MainContent">
                <div className="Class">
                    <h2 className="class">
                        {this.props.location.state.Name}
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <Tabs  className="Tabs" defaultActiveKey="1" centered>
                    <TabPane tab="Curriculum"  key="1">
                        <List
                        itemLayout="horizontal"
                        dataSource={this.state.Curriculum}
                        renderItem={item => (
                            <List.Item>
                                <Table striped bordered hover size="sm" >
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            #
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Title
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {item.Title}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </Table>
                            </List.Item>
                        )}
                        />
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="ClassWorks"  key="2">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="HomeWorks" key="3">
                        
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="Videos" key="4">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="Sessions" key="5">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="quizzes" key="6">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="Exams" key="7">
                    
                    </TabPane>
                </Tabs>
            </main>
            <br/>
            <footer className="Footer">Designed by Eng. Omar Redwan</footer>
        </div>
        )}
}
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` would trigger regardless if you check the previous props or not, but kudos if this resolved the issue.

Comment: But this condition prevents from always updating

Comment: Use useEffect hooks bro its easy